# Spring RequestMappingInfo compareTo order

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am interested in how the ordering of RequestMappings in Spring 3.2.x is supposed to work. I have tried this with versions 3.2.9 and 3.2.10. Given a request to url `/xxx/a/b/c` and matching mappings `/**`, `/xxx/{a}/{b}/{c}` and `/xxx/{a}/**`, the comparison in `RequestMappingHandlerMapping.lookupHandlerMethod` yields as best match `/**`. However, I would expect `/xxx/{a}/{b}/{c}` to be the best match. Can anyone explain this to me?

**Edit**
So I've looked into the code and found out that `RequestMappingInfo` uses `AntPathMatcher` to compare the pattern matches. What the latter does is to first check for exact matches, then count wildcards for each, braces for each, add them up and return the difference. Thus it evaluates `/**` as more specific than `/xxx/{a}/{b}/{c}`. However, this is incorrect IMO and previous versions of Spring used to have different behaviour. Can anyone comment on the issue or suggest a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implementex a quick fix by changing the declaration of `/**` to `/**/**/**`. It is ugly, but does absolutely the same as before and fixes the issue. I do hope that something will be done about it as part of the framework.